# Setup for Local Web Development with Docker

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, workflow, development-environment

I need advices for the workflow for web development with Docker:

Since today, we used Vagrant and/or MAMP for local development. To keep up with the times, we took a look at Docker and used it for some small projects. Now we want to update our workflow and only use Docker. I heard that the best practice is to use a separate container for every task. Most of our projects are done with Wordpress ([Bedrock](https://github.com/roots/bedrock)). So I would need at least 2 containers, one as webserver (Apache) and one for the data (MySQL). Furthermore I read, that people use a container for their frontend development as well, so they don't need to install Node/Bower/Yarn/Gulp over and over again on the local machine, and also in the different versions.

Our current workflow goes like this:

- Clone *bedrock*
- Clone *sage* starter theme in themes directory
- Git add .
- Commit everything into VCS, so co-workers can check it out
- Add project to vagrant config
- Install all dev dependencies (**composer** for bedrock, **npm** for sage)
- Start developing

How would that work with Docker?

I already read about docker-compose, but how can I achieve a proper workflow? I'm also rather confused about the COPY commands in Docker. Do I need to copy all the files into the Docker container?

I know, there are a lot of questions but maybe you can provide me with some easy-understandable tutorials or some links.